# What is the phase tag used for?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I found this [phase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phase) tag and I am wondering what it is used for, since it does not have any description in it.

Comment: Looks like it's a (relatively uncommon) misspelling of *phrase* (with an `r`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be *phrase.* I'll deal with it...

Comment: And (almost) no sooner said than done.

Comment: I think so too. Most of the questions are related to _phrases_ when I checked on them.